# Regular Expressions in MarkLogic's xQuery

Tags: regex, xquery, marklogic

I am trying an XQuery using `fn:matches` with a regular expression, but the MarkLogic implementation of XQuery does not seem to allow hexidecimal character representations. The following gives me an "**Invalid regular expression**" error.

```
(: Find text containing non-ISO-Latin characters :)
let $regex := '[^\x00-\xFF]'
let $results := fn:collection('mydocs')//myns:myelem[fn:matches(., $regex)]
let $count := fn:count($results)

return
    <figures count="{$count}">
        { $results }
    </figures>
```

However, this one does not give the error.

```
let $regex := '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
let $results := fn:collection('mydocs')//myns:myelem[fn:matches(., $regex)]
let $count := fn:count($results)

return
    <figures count="{$count}">
        { $results }
    </figures>
```

Is there a way to use the hexidecimal character representation, or an alternative that would give me the same result, in MarkLogic's implementation of XQuery?

Comment: Can you try the following code and let us know if it runs without error: `let $regex := '[^\x00\xFF]'`  If it runs, it means you have a problem with the range.  If it doesn't run, then MarkLogic regex will appear to not accept hexadecimal matches.

Comment: Thanks. It does indeed run:
    let $regex := '[^\x00-\xFF]' 
    return
      $regex
does not return an error

Comment: The problem is the hex characters in a range then.  Every regex engine has different escaping rules when you're using a character set (i.e. sometime engines require `\[a-z\]` others might need `[\x{00}]`.  It'll be hard to test without an actual MarkLogic console in front of me.

Comment: Can you use the `[[:ascii:]]` class in MarkLogic regex?  In your first example, you are essentially trying to match _any_ ASCII character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XQuery can use numeric character references in strings, in much the same way that XML and HTML can:

decimal: `"&#10;"`
hex: `"&#0a;"` (or just `"&#a;"`)

However, you can't represent some characters: `<= "&#x09;"`, for instance.

There's no regex type in XQuery (you just use a string as a regex), so you can use character references in your regular expressions:

```
fn:matches("a", "[^&#x09;-&#xFF;]")

(: => xs:boolean("false") :)
```

**Update**: here's the XQuery 1.0 spec on character references: http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#dt-character-reference.

Based on some brief testing, I think MarkLogic enforces XML 1.1 character reference rules: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets

For posterity, here are the XML 1.0 rules: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems MarkLogic's implementation of xQuery wants Unicode. As it turned out, even very small ranges in hex(e.g., `[^x00-x0F]`) threw the "Invalid regular expression" error, but Unicode notation did not throw the error. The following give me results.

```
let $regex := '[^U0000-U00FF]'
let $results := fn:collection('mydocs')//myns:myelem[fn:matches(., $regex)]
let $count := fn:count($results)

return
    <figures count="{$count}">
        { $results }
    </figures>
```

I think that the mere assignment of `let $regex := '[^\x00-\xFF]'` did not throw the error because it was treated as a string when I tried `return $regex`.

Comment: That regex is not matching unicode characters by hexadecimal codepoint; it's matching anything but `U00`, `0-U`, and `00FF` (ie, those ranges are interpreted as literal characters).